# NUnit CentOS 7 - TeamCity fails to run tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

While trying to run NUnit tests via TeamCity on Windows Server 2008 or Windows 10, there is no problem whatsoever. However, when trying to run it on CentOS, all build steps are finished correctly, except for that one, which should run the tests. I've spent a lot of time trying to find an answer for that, still yet to get one. Trace:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/bin/mono-sgen terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f8d4e51c597]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7f8d4e51c560]
/usr/bin/mono-sgen[0x5b5308]
/usr/bin/mono-sgen[0x426376]
/usr/bin/mono-sgen(mono_main+0x39b)[0x47ec9b]
/usr/bin/mono-sgen[0x41fdb5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f8d4e42fb15]
/usr/bin/mono-sgen[0x420149]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00764000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 539641950                          /usr/bin/mono-sgen
00963000-00964000 r--p 00363000 08:02 539641950                          /usr/bin/mono-sgen
00964000-0096e000 rw-p 00364000 08:02 539641950                          /usr/bin/mono-sgen
0096e000-009a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00ab2000-00af4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
41bd9000-41be9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d452e0000-7f8d45a4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 540166247                  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so
7f8d45a4a000-7f8d45c49000 ---p 0076a000 08:02 540166247                  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so
7f8d45c49000-7f8d45c4a000 r--p 00769000 08:02 540166247                  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so
7f8d45c4a000-7f8d45c4b000 rw-p 0076a000 08:02 540166247                  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so
7f8d45c4b000-7f8d45c69000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d45c69000-7f8d45fff000 r--p 00000000 08:02 540166245                  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
7f8d45fff000-7f8d46fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d46fff000-7f8d47000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d47000000-7f8d47c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:37054]
7f8d47ee8000-7f8d4e40e000 r--p 00000000 08:02 805308619                  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f8d4e40e000-7f8d4e5c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805308626                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f8d4e5c5000-7f8d4e7c5000 ---p 001b7000 08:02 805308626                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f8d4e7c5000-7f8d4e7c9000 r--p 001b7000 08:02 805308626                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f8d4e7c9000-7f8d4e7cb000 rw-p 001bb000 08:02 805308626                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f8d4e7cb000-7f8d4e7d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4e7d0000-7f8d4e7e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805306569                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f8d4e7e5000-7f8d4e9e4000 ---p 00015000 08:02 805306569                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f8d4e9e4000-7f8d4e9e5000 r--p 00014000 08:02 805306569                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f8d4e9e5000-7f8d4e9e6000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 805306569                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f8d4e9e6000-7f8d4e9fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805332888                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f8d4e9fc000-7f8d4ebfc000 ---p 00016000 08:02 805332888                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f8d4ebfc000-7f8d4ebfd000 r--p 00016000 08:02 805332888                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f8d4ebfd000-7f8d4ebfe000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 805332888                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f8d4ebfe000-7f8d4ec02000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4ec02000-7f8d4ec05000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805332868                  /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f8d4ec05000-7f8d4ee04000 ---p 00003000 08:02 805332868                  /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f8d4ee04000-7f8d4ee05000 r--p 00002000 08:02 805332868                  /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f8d4ee05000-7f8d4ee06000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 805332868                  /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f8d4ee06000-7f8d4ee0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805332892                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
7f8d4ee0d000-7f8d4f00c000 ---p 00007000 08:02 805332892                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
7f8d4f00c000-7f8d4f00d000 r--p 00006000 08:02 805332892                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
7f8d4f00d000-7f8d4f00e000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 805332892                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
7f8d4f00e000-7f8d4f10f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805332870                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f8d4f10f000-7f8d4f30e000 ---p 00101000 08:02 805332870                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f8d4f30e000-7f8d4f30f000 r--p 00100000 08:02 805332870                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f8d4f30f000-7f8d4f310000 rw-p 00101000 08:02 805332870                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f8d4f310000-7f8d4f331000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 805308282                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f8d4f463000-7f8d4f49c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f49c000-7f8d4f4c0000 r--p 00000000 08:02 537183558                  /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
7f8d4f4c0000-7f8d4f4c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f4c6000-7f8d4f525000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f525000-7f8d4f52b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f52b000-7f8d4f52f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f52f000-7f8d4f530000 rw-s 00000000 00:11 3854395                    /dev/shm/mono.37053
7f8d4f530000-7f8d4f531000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8d4f531000-7f8d4f532000 r--p 00021000 08:02 805308282                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f8d4f532000-7f8d4f533000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 805308282                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f8d4f533000-7f8d4f534000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff73346000-7fff73367000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff733c8000-7fff733ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono-sgen() [0x4ae002]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100) [0x7f8d4e9f5100]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f8d4e4435f7]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f8d4e444ce8]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75327) [0x7f8d4e483327]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37) [0x7f8d4e51c597]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0) [0x7f8d4e51c560]
    /usr/bin/mono-sgen() [0x5b5308]
    /usr/bin/mono-sgen() [0x426376]
    /usr/bin/mono-sgen(mono_main+0x39b) [0x47ec9b]
    /usr/bin/mono-sgen() [0x41fdb5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f8d4e42fb15]
    /usr/bin/mono-sgen() [0x420149]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Process exited with code 134
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Nunit console runner to use v3.

Download the nunit 3.x from nunit.org then extract it on to your build agent machine.

On your Nunit build step, change the NUnit runner to 3.0 then give it the path to the nunit3-console.exe